# OCaml: new_line equivalent before 3.11

Tags: compilation, makefile, ocaml, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to compile [Libra toolkit](http://libra.cs.uoregon.edu/) on a machine running Ubuntu Hardy with OCaml 3.10, I can't upgrade the OS nor update OCaml, and I don't know anything about OCaml. There is only one line that gives me an unbound value error because it uses the **new_line** function, which was introduced in OCaml 3.11 (http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Lexing.html), could someone tell me how to change it to be compatible with OCaml 3.10? It's the line near the end of this code:

```
{
open MnParseTypes;;
open MnParser;;
(* Raised when parsing ends *)
exception Eof;;

module L = Lexing
let linenum lexbuf = lexbuf.L.lex_curr_p.L.pos_lnum

let line = ref 1;;

let keywords = Hashtbl.create 10
let _ = 
  List.iter2 (Hashtbl.add keywords)
    ["mn"; "features"; "tree"; "table"; "w"; "eof"]
    [Tmn; Tfeatures; Ttree; Ttable; Tweight; EOF];;
}

let digits = ['0'-'9']+
let identifier = ['a'-'z' 'A'-'Z']+

rule lexer = parse
(* eat blank characters *)
    [' ' '\t'] {lexer lexbuf}
(* | "Feature list:" {lexer lexbuf} *)
  | '{' {Tlbrace}
  | '}' {Trbrace}
  | '(' {Tlparen}
  | ')' {Trparen}
  | ('-')? "inf" {Tfloat( float_of_string(L.lexeme lexbuf))}
  | identifier {
      let x = String.lowercase (Lexing.lexeme lexbuf) in
      try Hashtbl.find keywords x
      with Not_found -> 
        failwith((Lexing.lexeme lexbuf) 
          ^ ": unknown identifier on line " ^ string_of_int (linenum lexbuf))}
  | digits {Tint (int_of_string (L.lexeme lexbuf))}
  | ('-')? digits ('.' digits)? (['e' 'E'] ['+' '-']? digits)? 
      {Tfloat( float_of_string(L.lexeme lexbuf))}
  | '+' 'v' (digits as var) '_' (digits as value) 
      {Tcond(true, int_of_string var, int_of_string value)}
  | '-' 'v' (digits as var) '_' (digits as value) 
      {Tcond(false, int_of_string var, int_of_string value)}
  | 'v' (digits as var) '_' (digits as value) 
      {Tvar( int_of_string var, int_of_string value)}
  | ['\n' '\r']+ {L.new_line lexbuf; TEOL}   (* THIS GIVES THE ERROR *)
  | eof {EOF}
  | _ {failwith((L.lexeme lexbuf) ^ 
       ": mistake on line " ^ string_of_int lexbuf.L.lex_curr_p.L.pos_lnum)}
```

Comment: This will help, it's actually the function that does what I want, but I don't know how to insert it in my code: http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=3930

Comment: I tried using this: 
`(* let start_next_line lexbuf = () *)

let start_next_line lexbuf =
   let lcp = lexbuf.lex_curr_p in
   lexbuf.lex_curr_p <- {
      lcp with
      pos_lnum = lcp.pos_lnum + 1;
      pos_bol = lcp.pos_cnum;}
    }`  and then `| ['\n' '\r']+ {start_next_line lexbuf; TEOL}` but I get the error **Fatal error: exception Data.Eof** sometimes

Comment: you really should include these in your question body if it's relevant.

Comment: That `Data.Eof` issue seems unrelated to your problem: apparently your code seems correct (it does compile, and is the same as the one in lexing), so I would try to see if the data you feed it with is correct, or report to the maintainer. Note that it's not production ready code.

Comment: btw, it would be nice to point to the file containing the issue, not just c&p the code.

Comment: The data is correct and it works on Libra 0.5, but it causes that error with the change in gasche's answer. In fact, Libra has another file that works in this way. IDK if this is worth reporting, I'm trying to make the source compatible with an older version of OCaml, it's not useful unless someone is in the exact same situation as me. The source is in [Libra 0.5.0](http://libra.cs.uoregon.edu/libra-tk-0.5.0.tar.gz), and there are two files like this: src/mn/mnLexer.mll (line 46) and src/bn/cnLexer.mll (line 48), and the one which includes the function is src/bn/bifLexer.mll (line 27).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the directory of the OCaml sources (from SVN or a relase tarball), the source of the module `Foo` of the standard library will be in `stdlib/foo.{ml,mli}` (`.mli` is the interface file, `.ml` the implementation file). Looking at `stdlib/lexing.ml` gives you:

```
let new_line lexbuf =
  let lcp = lexbuf.lex_curr_p in
  lexbuf.lex_curr_p <- { lcp with
    pos_lnum = lcp.pos_lnum + 1;
    pos_bol = lcp.pos_cnum;
  }
```

You can implement this in your code as well, using `open Lexing` to have the field names in scope, or using `lexbuf.Lexing.lex_curr_p`, and `{ lcp with Lexing.pos_lnum = lcp.Lexing.pos_lnum ...` instead.

Edit: as you probably don't plan to hack the OCaml code yourself, let's give you the full thing:

```
let new_line lexbuf =
  let lcp = lexbuf.Lexing.lex_curr_p in
  lexbuf.Lexing.lex_curr_p <- { lcp with
    Lexing.pos_lnum = lcp.Lexing.pos_lnum + 1;
    Lexing.pos_bol = lcp.Lexing.pos_cnum;
  }
```

add this at the top of the file that uses `new_line` (if it says `Lexing.new_line`, turn it into `new_line`), and you should be fine.

Comment: I tried that but I get a segmentation fault and "Fatal error: exception Data.Eof" with some of the input files and the only thing I see in them is that they might be bigger than the others.

Comment: I just found I had made a mistake when modifying the files, I did as you said and changed the line that parses the new lines to   `| ['\n' '\r']+ {new_line lexbuf; TEOL}` and now it works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can implement `new_line` yourself but I think upgrading OCaml would be better. I know that you said you can't upgrade the OS but installing the newer version of Ocaml can be done in your home directory without the need of any superuser privilege. [OPAM](http://opam.ocamlpro.com/) is a packet manager for OCaml that makes it very easy to install the latest version of OCaml.

Comment: I can't install OPAM, I can't change the sources.list and I get "couldn't resolve host" when trying to download ocamlbrew with curl. I can use apt-get with no problem but I can't use curl or wget.

Comment: just grab the source of ocaml and compile it; it's not really hard. OPAM is great because it streamlines the process even more, and make it very simple to handle dependencies, but if you don't have that many libraries to install, you can just build everything "by hand" (ie. `configure && make && make install`). You could even have a look at the debian package dependencies to know which sources you need (for everything else than ocaml lang), and use the debian packaging data to integrate your builds properly with the system.

Comment: since you are using Ubuntu, why not upgrading to a newer version?